# ubuntu softwre tool doesn't work

Tags: firefox

I click on the 'ubuntu software' icon and the window comes up, but never resolves, it never finds anything.  the reason it's a problem is because firefox started working a bit crazy.  Many youtube videos won't play and duckduckgo.com search engine doesn't come up, or it does some of the time.  I tried uninstalling firefox from the terminal but it doesn't go away.

Comment: I added firefox through the terminal and now I have 2 firefoxes.   How do I get rid of the first one that doesn't work?   And how do I get 'ubuntu software' to work?

Comment: And how do you un-install something installed through 'ubuntu software' (snap?)

Answer (score 0):

running the following command:

```
sudo snap remove firefox
```

This will remove the default Firefox installation in Ubuntu, as snaps are the only "out of the box" versions of Firefox.